# Arbitrage possible?

Tags: arbitrage, money-transfer

The last days I was thinking about arbitrage trading because the prices differ between several exchanges. So I started thinking if this could work and I'm stuck in one point. If I deposit money on exchange A and buy coins for 100$ each. Then transferring the money to exchange B and sell them for 110$ each I will make some profit. But I'm thinking on how to get the money back to exchange A to start over again.

I could do this my withdrawing via bank wire or something but this is expensive and slow. Transferring bitcoins is quite easy but is there any suitable way on how to exchange USD/EUR/whatever from one exchange to another!?

Comment: related: [Why don't people buy at one exchange and sell at another?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12670/5406)

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the catch. If it were not for the time and expense of moving fiat money around, you wouldn't expect to see these apparent arbitrage opportunities sitting around.