# Why are Bitcoin prices so different between different markets?

Tags: trading

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm new to this stuff.

Currently, according to cryptocoincharts.info, Bitcoins are trading at $1050 on BTC-E but $1228 on Mt. Gox. How is this possible? What would cause such a large price discrepancy? Shouldn't it be possible to capitalize on this difference by buying at BTC-E and selling at Mt. Gox, and if so shouldn't that tend to equalize the trading prices?

Comment: Mtgox has dolor withdrawal problems. So, dolor with mtgox worth (valued) less. So, you pay more dolors and take your bitcoins out. So, the higher exchange rate.

Comment: @vi.su. Is the same true for Bitstamp? I see that the Bitstamp rate is also considerably higher than BTC-E, $1130.

Comment: similar to [Is there an efficient way to exploit arbitrages between the different exchanges?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/121/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-exploit-arbitrages-between-the-different-exchanges)

Answer (score 0):

Mtgox has dollar withdrawal problems. So a dollar within Mt. Gox is worth (valued) less. So you pay more dollars and take your bitcoins out, hence the higher exchange rate.